# Plotting graphics under a loop operation in R

Tags: r, loops, graphics

The script below runs and plots the bayesian change point (bcp) of a data series with 6 columns of data referenced here as x <-13:18 i.e. columns 13 through 18 in the data file 2GB01.csv. The problem is that only the output plot of column 18 is plotted. I need the script modified to plot the 6 graphs for each column data set in one graphic window partition.
Any help?

The data file looks something like this....
col1 col2 ....col13 col14 col15 col16 col17 col18
11    14       17    87    90    10     20    76
23    87       87    16    09    17     87    65
.     .        .     .     .     .      .     .
.     .        .     .     .     .      .     .
.     .        .     .     .     .      .     .

The script is as written below....

enter code here

```
  data2<-read.csv("2GB01.csv", header=TRUE, row.names=1)

    x <- 13:18
    for(i in seq(along=x)){
        ond<-data2[,i]
        bcp.1<-bcp(as.vector(ond))
    if (require("strucchange")) {
    bp <- breakpoints(ond ~ 1, h = 2)$breakpoints
    rho <- rep(0, length(ond))
    rho[bp] <- 1
    b.num<-1 + c(0,cumsum(rho[1:(length(rho)-1)]))
    bp.mean <- unlist(lapply(split(ond,b.num),mean))
    bp.ri <- rep(0,length(ond))


    for (i in 1:length(bp.ri)) bp.ri[i] <- bp.mean[b.num[i]]
        xax<-seq(1960, 2010, length=51)
        op <- par(mfrow=c(2,1),col.lab="black",col.main="black")
        op2 <- par(mar=c(0,4,4,4.5),xaxt="n",yaxt="n", cex.axis=0.75,las=2)
        plot(xax, ond, col="grey", pch=20, xlab="",ylab="", axes=T)
        lines(xax, bcp.1$posterior.mean, lwd=2)
        axis(4, yaxt="s")
        mtext('Posterior mean', las=0, side=4, line=3.5)
        lines(bp.ri, col="blue")
        par(op2)
        op3 <- par(mar=c(5,4,0,4.5), xaxt="s",yaxt="n", cex.axis=0.75,las=2)
plot(xax, bcp.1$posterior.prob, xlab="Year", ylab="Posterior   probability",     type="l", xlim=c(1960,2010), ylim=c(0,1),las=0)
    for (i in 1:length(bp.ri)) abline(v=xax[bp[i]], col="blue")
        axis(2, yaxt="s")
        par(op3)
        par(op)


} else {
  cat("strucchange is not loaded")
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this to the outside of your loop:

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,1),col.lab="black",col.main="black")
```

If you call it each time, it sets up the grid of plots each time (e.g. clears it).

You'll need to do something like `mfrow=c(2,length(rp.ri))`.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but still it doesn't work. I get the error "Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large". I have attempted to reduce the plot margins but still I get the same error. I forgot to mention that for the script to run one has to load the "bcp" and "strucchange" packages in R.

Comment: That likely has to do with all the other insanity you have in there.  Start with the basics: the `par()` call, a `for` loop, and inside just a single plot command per iteration of the loop.  Then build it back up to look the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks Ari, You were right I only had to move the "op <- par(mfrow=c(2,1),col.lab="black",col.main="black") outside the loop but had to substitute the mfrow with mfcol :) that was silly of me. Cheers.